# Migrating from Sharepoint 2013/excel services to Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, migration, excel-services

Does anyone know of a migration path from Sharepoint 2013/Excel Services to Office 365?  We have a bunch of Excel workbooks stored in SP 2013, which we calculate using Excel Services via the Excel Services web service.  Now Our company is moving to Office 365, and I have not been able to find anything about how to move from our scenario to O365.  We have a web app which uses the excel services web service api to inject data into workbooks stored on sharepoint, then retrieve these workbooks and stream them to the browser.  Hopefully there is an Office 365 approach which can perform in the same way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Excel web service is not longer a feature available in SharePoint Online. You will need to recreate a new solution for you scenario.